# Dynamic chart series data from parameter (SSRS)

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, charts

How to create a dynamic series chart in SSRS. I have four parameter. On selection of a parameter the chart will draw. I mean the serial name of the chart will not hard code. The series name will come form the parameter. I used the expression in series area like this "=Parameters!MyDuration.Value" where MyDuration is my parameter. But it did not work. Please guide me how to write the expression or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the solution of my issue. The dynamic series name from the parameter will be like this. =Sum(Fields(Parameters!MyParameterName.Value).Value).